# SceneKit Will not fill the screen in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, xcode12, xcode12beta5

I am trying to make practice with SceneKit and making IOS games. In Xcode 12 Beta 5, but the SceneView will not fill up the screen no matter what I do, this with the default code when starting a game with SceneKit. When I use Xcode 11 it fills up the screen, but I am unable to open sin files in Xcode 11.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3BvP.jpg)

Comment: Hi Lucas, welcome to SO. Can you please the part of the code where you configure the SceneView?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had pasted that, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding a Launch screen storyboard and adding it to the plist, you can also add your main storyboard as the launch screen.

edit:

The best way to fix this is select your project and under General->App icons and launch images->Launch Screen File = Main

Comment: How did you exactly solve it? I'm not able to add to the .plist file.

Comment: What does it do when you try to add it to the .plist?

Comment: @SalihOzdemir you can just set "Launch Screen File' as Main under General tab, then it should work