# SpriteKit screen size problem with swift5

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I try to learn SpriteKit with Xcode 12.4 and swift5.
When I made the first project and tried to run the simulator, it showed me a screen like in the below image.

You can see that screen is not full-size. So, I've changed the size of the attribute `inspector` in `GameScene.sks` but nothing changed.

`GameViewController` code is like below, I didn't change anything... How can I make my `GameScene` fullscreen on a simulator of iPhone 11?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Scene is centered with black gap on left and right, device is in landscape]

Comment: Change the scale mode to whichever is appropriate.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63624557/14351818

Comment: @aheze thank you bro. I have resolved this issue follow your link. 